# Websphere Log4j2 classpath issue

Tags: java, websphere, classpath, log4j2

I'm deploying an utility jar in websphere that publishes couple of APIs. Now these API would be called by a webapplication.  Now this jar uses log4j2 for logging. I have tried to create an uber jar by adding the packages from the two log4j2 jars ( log4j-api-2.0.2.jar && log4j-core-2.0.2.jar). I'm doing this by using ant to build the utility jar.

Here is the snippet of the ant code that builds up the jar for me

```
<!--Creates the client jar file  -->
<target name="clientjar" depends="compile">


    <jar destfile="${dist.dir}/client/myUtility.jar" basedir="${class.dir}">    

        <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="*.jar" />

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Built-By" value="${user.name}" />
            <attribute name="Build-Date" value="${timestamp}" />
            <section name="${ant.project.name}">
                <attribute name="Implementation-Title" value="${project.implementation.title}"/>
                <attribute name="Specification-Version" value="${project.version}"/>
            </section>
        </manifest>

    </jar>
</target>
```

My issue is when the web application that is sitting  on the same jvm invokes the jar api,  log4j spits out the following error message

ERROR StatusLogger Log4j2 could not find a logging implementation. Please add log4j-core to the classpath. Using SimpleLogger to log to the console...

Any pointers would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you unzip the log4j-core jar and re-zip it as part of a bigger jar file, make VERY sure to include ALL files that were originally in the log4j-core jar. It contains a number of config files that the log4j-api will look for. If these files are absent you will get the error you ran into.

Comment: I did compare the rezipped version with the original version. Everything seems to be okay except for the manifest.mf file. The manifest file seems to differ from the manifest file that came along with the original jar. Do you think it to be a concern?